# From python list to php array

Tags: php, python, arrays, json

I have a python script `get_telemetry.py` that results in this data:

```
voltage = [[14.766786195683332, u'2017-10-11T06:00:00Z'], [14.756422268006672, u'2017-10-11T07:00:00Z'], [14.213013911141665, u'2017-10-11T08:00:00Z']]
```

I am trying to send this data to a php script where it will be converted into a php array, that will eventually end up in a google chart:

```
$voltagedata = ["2017-10-11 06:00:00" => 14.76, "2017-10-11 07:00:00"=> 14.75, "2017-10-11 08:00:00" => 14.21]
```

But when I try to encode the python list into json:
 `print json.dumps(voltage)`

and then try decode it in php:

```
$result = shell_exec('get_telemetry.py ' .  $imei);
```

`$voltagedata = json_decode($result, true)`

I get this error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion
```

How can I get that python list of lists into a php array?
I've tried to pass the python list into a dictionary first, but this gives me the same result. ie : [from this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235467/passing-a-python-list-to-php)

Comment: When you print ANYTHING to the shell, it becomes a string. You need to parse the string in your php script (not sure how to do that in php)

Comment: Make sure you `print json.dumps(data)` from your python script. Right now it looks like you have `print data`! Also, in PHP, use `json_decode`.

Comment: I don't use PHP, but don't you need `json_decode`?

Comment: which line number the warning come from? I guess the culprit is “$imei”