# Pass multiple lists from Python to a PHP array?

Tags: python, php

Im trying to get multiple lists from a python script to PHP. Going off from this question [Passing a Python list to php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235467/passing-a-python-list-to-php/17235651), Im using Json.

Python:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
print(json.dumps(list1))
print(json.dumps(list2))
```

For PHP I tried multiple ways:

```
json_decode(exec("test.py", $return), true);

var_dump($return);
```

This gives the two lists as an array of strings.

(array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "[1, 2, 3]" [1]=> string(9) "[4, 5, 6]")

Using

```
$output = json_decode(exec("test.py", $return), true);

var_dump($output);
```

only gives the second list as an array.

Using `print(json.dumps([list1,list2]))` in Python gives the two lists as a single string.

How can I get multiple lists as arrays in PHP? Or is there a better way to parse the lists in PHP?

Comment: You should just be able to do this in python: `print([list1, list2])`

Comment: @C_Z_ This just gives one long string same as  ```print(json.dumps([list1,list2]))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mixing things up.
Your first python example produces 2 valid json string which together are invalid json.

Then `exec` returns the **last** line of output and stores each line as a single entry in the second argument (`$return`).

So you python should look like:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
# Print one line of json
print(json.dumps([list1, list2]))
```

And PHP:

```
$output = exec("test.py");
$data = json_decode($output, true);

// OR
$output = [];
exec("test.py", $output);

$data = json_decode($output[0], true);
```

Comment: Thanks, your second example is what worked for me. Now each list is accessible as an array through output[]